# Can't make multiselectselect update immediately

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to implement a "Better list example" from the knockout official site: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

I am displaying the list of skills, and everything works great, except for the UI updating of multiselect. When i click the Add button, the observable property updates immediately, but to see any changes in the multiselect I have to click on it in the UI, then the new Skill appears on the display.

I tried to use change and blur events: valueupdate: 'change', no success.

**Model**

```
self.allSkills = ko.observableArray("");
self.skillToAdd = ko.observable("");
self.selectedSkills = ko.observableArray("");

self.addSkill = function() {
                    self.allSkills().push(self.skillToAdd());
                    self.skillToAdd("");
                };
```

**View**

```
<form data-bind="submit: $root.addSkill">
  <label>Required Skills:</label>
  Add skill: <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.skillToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
  <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: $root.skillToAdd().length>0">Add</button>
</form>
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: $root.allSkills, optionsText: $data, selectedOptions: $root.selectedSkills">
</select>
```

Comment: _multiselectselect_? what is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing into the underlying array's value.  Push into the ObservableArray itself -

```
self.addSkill = function() {
    var valueToPush = self.skillToAdd();
    self.allSkills.push(valueToPush);
    self.skillToAdd(null);
};
```